# How to check in Go if variable of type Interface is of certain struct type that implements it?

Tags: go

Lets say that I have the following:

```
type A Interface{
   ....
}

//Implements A
type B struct{
   ....
}

//Imlements A
type C struct{
   ....
}
```

And now I have a function which accepts variable of type `A` as an argument:

```
func Foo(obj A){
     if A is B{
          ....
     }else if A is C{
          ....
     }
}
```

And a `main` function:

```
func main(){

    b := B{}
    Foo(b)

}
```

How can I check if the argument passed to the function is actually type `B`?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) as mentioned the tour page linked by @CeriseLimón.

```
func Foo(v A) {
    switch v := v.(type) {
    case B:
        // It's a B
    case C:
        // It's a C
    }
}
```

[See it in action in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lyKrmyts7hn).